# How to "vertically stack" Control.Frames?

Tags: haskell, conduit, haskell-pipes

In the `pipes` package, the tutorial `Control.Pipes.Tutorial` [1] shows how to "vertically stack" pipe components using the monad `>>` operator.

How would I go about doing that with Control.Frame?

For example, using the definitions from the Control.Frame tutorial:

```
source1 = fromList [1..10]
source2 = fromList [30..40]

-- combine two sources:

runFrame $ printer <-< (source1 ??? source2)

-- combine two transformers:

runFrame $ printer <-< (take' 3 ??? take' 2) <-< fromList [1..]
```

Using `>>` here for `???` doesn't typecheck.

[1] http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/latest/doc/html/Control-Pipe-Tutorial.html#g:4

Update: Here is a paste of what I've been trying: http://hpaste.org/77986

It looks like `close` is the problem -- see the function `bar8` in the above paste.
The frames are composable with `>>` if I don't explicitly `close` them. Of course, I eventually need to close them. Hmmm....

Answer (score 1):

A `Frame` isn't a monad, it's an indexed monad. This means that the normal monad operators won't work, and you have to import the indexed versions of them. According to [the tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/2.5.0/doc/html/Control-Frame-Tutorial.html), this means adding the following to the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}

import Control.Frame
import Control.IMonad.Do
import Control.IMonad.Trans
import Prelude hiding (Monad(..))
```

Comment: I am running the tutorial code, and I have those imports at the top of my file. So what would be the analogous operator for indexed monads? Or what would be the fully qualified name of the function I need to use to vertically stack the Frame components?

Comment: It should work with the code that you posted, since the operator has exactly the same name. Please post the error that you receive upon compilation for further assistance.

Comment: See the update to the problem - I've included the code I'm working with.

Comment: Well, you found it out by yourself. If the first frame closes the resource, the second frame can't use it any more.